# Sci fi story about fruit that gave its consumers power

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I once read a children's scifi story. I think it maybe came out in the '80s.  It was about a farmer whose fruit garden got mysteriously imbued with some sort of strange substance. This led to people who ate it magically getting cliched powers, like the ability to see through things, teleport, etc.

Despite the cheesy premise, 10-year-old me had been very, very invested in it, and if I remember correctly, the writing itself was of a slightly advanced, flowery style.

Some more things that I think I can remember:

- it was short (maybe 90-100 pages)
- there wasn't really an antagonist, or even much of a plot- rather, the idea was to just watch the crazy antics of everybody involved, particularly those of the lucky people who got powers
- the farmer's kids were the first to eat the fruit, and his son promptly burned half the house down (don't remember what the power was, though)
- ultimately, the story ended with the fruit-season ending, people losing their supply and their powers eventually fizzling away
- the author's first name began -- I think -- with an 'M'.

What book might this be? This is literally all I can remember, but I'd very much like to find it again, if only so that I can cringe at it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this an illustrated book, or just a regular book?  Do you remember the cover or any interior art?

Comment: @DavidW - it was a regular chapter book, and no, I can't remember the cover (no interior art)

Comment: My first thought, with farms and things magically having properties, were the Fleishman McBroom books, but there it was the things being grown growing much faster and larger, not imbuing powers, as best I recall.